# Java class file truncated

Tags: java, spring, maven, aspectj

I have two projects. My one project (say project2) depends on another project(project2). Both projects are maven project and project1 is listed in dependancies of project2. When I compile project2, all the class files from project1 should be copied to project2 (I imagine). But, I see that the file size of one of the class files in project1 is different than file size of class file for the same class in project2. If I decompile the files I get following results.

Decompiled FacebookUserDetail.class from project1:

```
package com.***.domain.user.external;

import com.***.domain.user.UserDetailType;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.runtime.internal.CFlowCounter;
import org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.Factory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect;
import org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl;

@Configurable
@Entity
public class FacebookUserDetail extends ExternalUserDetail
{
  public FacebookUserDetail()
  {
    JoinPoint localJoinPoint = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_1, this, this); if ((!AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.ajc$if$bb0((Configurable)getClass().getAnnotation(Configurable.class))) && (AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.ajc$if$6f1(localJoinPoint))) AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aspectOf().ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$2$1ea6722c(this);
  }

  public static FacebookUserDetail findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId(String facebookId)
  {
    String str = facebookId; JoinPoint localJoinPoint = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_0, null, null, str); if ((AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.ajc$cflowCounter$1.isValid()) && (AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.hasAspect())) return (FacebookUserDetail)findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId_aroundBody1$advice(str, localJoinPoint, AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.aspectOf(), null, ajc$tjp_0, localJoinPoint); return findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId_aroundBody0(str, localJoinPoint);
  }

  public UserDetailType getExternalUserDetailType()
  {
    return UserDetailType.FACEBOOK;
  }

  static
  {
    ajc$preClinit(); } 
  public static long countFacebookUserDetails() { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$countFacebookUserDetails(); } 
  public static List<FacebookUserDetail> findAllFacebookUserDetails() { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$findAllFacebookUserDetails(); } 
  public static FacebookUserDetail findFacebookUserDetail(Long paramLong) { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$findFacebookUserDetail(paramLong); } 
  public static List<FacebookUserDetail> findFacebookUserDetailEntries(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Entity$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$findFacebookUserDetailEntries(paramInt1, paramInt2); } 
  public static TypedQuery<FacebookUserDetail> findFacebookUserDetailsByUserIdEquals(String paramString) { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Finder.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_Finder$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$findFacebookUserDetailsByUserIdEquals(paramString); } 
  public String toString() { return FacebookUserDetail_Roo_ToString.ajc$interMethod$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail_Roo_ToString$com_nim_domain_user_external_FacebookUserDetail$toString(this); }

}
```

Decompiled FacebookUserDetail.class from project2

```
package com.***.domain.user.external;

import com.***.domain.user.UserDetailType;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.runtime.internal.CFlowCounter;
import org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.Factory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect;
import org.springframework.mock.staticmock.AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl;

public class FacebookUserDetail extends ExternalUserDetail
{
  public FacebookUserDetail()
  {
    JoinPoint localJoinPoint = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_1, this, this); if ((!AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.ajc$if$bb0((Configurable)getClass().getAnnotation(Configurable.class))) && (AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.ajc$if$6f1(localJoinPoint))) AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aspectOf().ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_beans_factory_aspectj_AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect$2$1ea6722c(this);
  }

  public static FacebookUserDetail findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId(String facebookId)
  {
    String str = facebookId; JoinPoint localJoinPoint = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_0, null, null, str); if ((AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.ajc$cflowCounter$1.isValid()) && (AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.hasAspect())) return (FacebookUserDetail)findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId_aroundBody1$advice(str, localJoinPoint, AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl.aspectOf(), null, ajc$tjp_0, localJoinPoint); return findFacebookUserDetailByFacebookId_aroundBody0(str, localJoinPoint);
  }

  public UserDetailType getExternalUserDetailType()
  {
    return UserDetailType.FACEBOOK;
  }

  static
  {
    ajc$preClinit();
  }
}
```

My question is: What are possible reasons for truncated class file in project2?

Comment: The class files of the dependent project are normally installed on the maven local repository. Are you sure that the copied classes come from maven and not your IDE or other builders?

Comment: We make installable debian packages that are independent of local maven repository. So, I dont think copied classes come from maven.

Comment: Check what compilers are generating these classes. Different compilers may lead to different classes and consequently different decompiled source.

Comment: We use maven aspectj plugin. I think that plugin is what is adding finder methods to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning this part: *When I compile project2, all the class files from project1 should be copied to project2*

This is actually not the case, maven compiles the two projects into two separate jars if the projects are of jar type, or copies  project1.jar into WEB-INF/lib of project2 if project 2 is of type WAR.

The difference between the two class files shows that the version of project2 does not have the Roo aspects applied to it, although it was compiled with AspectJ as well.

Try to build the project from the command line only by closing all IDEs and compare the two versions to see if the same problem remains. It could be that your IDE is compiling the class with aspectJ but without the correct Roo aspects.

Also have a look at this [report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287581/how-can-i-make-sure-that-aspects-generated-by-spring-roo-are-woven-by-a-dependen) on having to add the aspectj plugin on both the dependent and the depending project, and this documentation on [3.7.2.2. Limitations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/architecture.html) on Roo multi-module maven support.

Comment: I have just been given a debian package that has described scenario. I cannot reproduce it in current builds. Although problem is solved, we want to know the precise reason why this problem existed in the first place.

Comment: then it means that the build of the version in the debian package was not made using maven or was done with a version of the build that had some bug. try checking with whom generated the package, and see what they used to make the build and which version